# How to chain MotionLayout animation

Tags: android-constraintlayout, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

My task is to animate the movement of a button from "off" the screen, first, to the center of the screen, then, up to the top (see the attached xml and screenshots). So basically, I have to "chain" 2 animations. My question is:
how can I do it using only 1 transition?

I implemented it using Transition.TransitionListener, using doOnEnd() ktx function. And it works fine, but the code can be complicated, since I am also planning to remove the listener in onDestroy() to prevent memory leaks.

Here is the layout by default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Here is the result of the 1st animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

And here is the result of the 2nd animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

The activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            val transitionPhase1 = transitionPhase1()
            transitionPhase1.doOnEnd {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root, transitionPhase2())
            }
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root, transitionPhase1)
        }, 2000)
    }

    private fun transitionPhase1(): Transition {
        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_phase_1)
        constraintSet.applyTo(root)
        return AutoTransition()
    }

    private fun transitionPhase2(): Transition {
        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_phase_2)
        constraintSet.applyTo(root)
        return AutoTransition()
    }
}
```

I expect to have only 1 TransitionManger.beginDelayedTransition() method call.
[image: phase 0]
[image: phase 1]
[image: phase 2]

Comment: what triggers this animation? scroll?

Comment: In the provided code above it start after a 2 second delay.
But I will have to port this transition to a different project, there the tranisition is triggered by an http requests response.

Comment: you cannot use motion layout for this kind of animations and to be honest you are not using motion layout at all, you just using the motionlayout tag. [Please read here](https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-i-29208674b10d)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that you do not "chain two transitions" but use one transition with keyframes to solve the two motions. This is exactly what `<KeyFrame>` is made for.

For this I would recommend to create a scene.xml file to handle the constraintsets and the transition.

You would then only have start and end as constraintSet and the the inbetween state you set up as keyframe.

Let me know if you need examples on how to set this up.

Comment: can you please provide an example

Answer (score -1):

You can chain the  as I have done it below:

[GitHub](https://github.com/inspire-coding/RegistrationFlow_1/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/activity_main_scene.xml)

```
<Transition
    android:id="@+id/startToEnd_materialCardView_email"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end_materialCardView_email"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start_materialCardView_email"
    app:duration="500">
    <OnClick
        app:clickAction="toggle"
        app:targetId="@+id/start_materialCardView_email" />
</Transition>
<Transition
    android:id="@+id/endToStart_materialCardView_email"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/start_materialCardView_email"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/end_materialCardView_email"
    app:duration="500">
    <OnClick
        app:clickAction="toggle"
        app:targetId="@+id/end_materialCardView_email" />
</Transition>

<Transition
    android:id="@+id/startToEnd_materialCardView_password"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end_materialCardView_password"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/end_materialCardView_email"
    app:duration="500">
    <OnClick
        app:clickAction="toggle"
        app:targetId="@+id/start_materialCardView_password" />
</Transition>
<Transition
    android:id="@+id/endToStart_materialCardView_password"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end_materialCardView_email"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/end_materialCardView_password"
    app:duration="500">
    <OnClick
        app:clickAction="toggle"
        app:targetId="@+id/end_materialCardView_password" />
</Transition>

<Transition
    android:id="@+id/startToEnd_materialCardView_birthDate"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end_materialCardView_birthDate"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/end_materialCardView_password"
    app:duration="500">
    <OnClick
        app:clickAction="toggle"
        app:targetId="@+id/start_materialCardView_birthDate" />
</Transition>
<Transition
    android:id="@+id/endToStart_materialCardView_birthDate"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end_materialCardView_password"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/end_materialCardView_birthDate"
    app:duration="500">
    <OnClick
        app:clickAction="toggle"
        app:targetId="@+id/end_materialCardView_birthDate" />
</Transition>

<Transition
    android:id="@+id/startToEnd_materialCardView_phoneNumber"
    app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end_materialCardView_phoneNumber"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/end_materialCardView_birthDate"
    app:duration="1000">
    <OnClick
        app:clickAction="toggle"
        app:targetId="@+id/materialCardView_phoneNumber" />
</Transition>
```

[Inspire Coding](https://inspirecoding.app/)